# TypeError: <Array>.each is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three references to three drop downs on my page, and as each one is changed, I want to run a JavaScript function called `validateForm();`

My code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var drpSupplier         = document.getElementById('supplier');
    var drpChargeRate       = document.getElementById('formElementChargeRate');
    var drpIDSEmail         = document.getElementById('formElementEmailIDS');
    var formLevel2DDs       = new Array();

    formLevel2DDs.push(drpSupplier);
    formLevel2DDs.push(drpChargeRate);
    formLevel2DDs.push(drpIDSEmail);

    formLevel2DDs.each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            validateForm()
        });
    });
});
```

But this code is giving me the error:

> TypeError: formLevel2DDs.each is not a function

I am using jQuery version 1.8.3 (it is a legacy system).

Comment: Perhaps you meant `forEach`, or `$.each(formLevel2DDs, function(){})`?

Comment: Why jQuery and `document.getElementById` in the same snippet?

Comment: @moonwave99 `getElementById` is well-supported cross-browser and is much, much faster than doing the same with jQuery.

Comment: And now that nearly all of us don't have to worry about IE prior to IE8, we don't have to worry about the fact that `getElementById` was broken in IE7 and earlier.

Comment: @ciwan It's not necessary to use a loop in this case, just use .change on the array wrapped with jQuery

Comment: @Anton: Nicely spotted!

Comment: @Anton I did what you said, but now I get `TypeError: formLevel2DDs.change is not a function` :(

Comment: @Ciwan you need to wrap the array with jQuery like this : `$(formLevel2DDs).change`

Comment: Thanks Anton, I did it like @T.J.Crowder suggested using your well spotted tidying of code and it now works :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no `each` function on arrays.

As [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696560/anton) points out in the comments, you don't need `each` at all for what you're doing; see below the fold.

But if you want `each`, you have three choices:

1. Wrap your array in a jQuery instance and use jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/): `$(formLevel2DDs).each(function(index, entry) { ... });`
2. Use jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each): `$.each(formLevel2DDs, function(index, entry) { ... });`

   Note that this is not the same function as above.
3. Use `forEach` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) | [Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18)): `formLevel2DDs.forEach(function(entry, index, array) { ... });`

   Note that `forEach` is new as of ECMAScript5. All modern browsers have it, but you'll need a shim/polyfill for older ones (like IE8). Also note that the order of the arguments to the callback is different than either of the options above.

---

But to Anton's point, you can do that much more simply:

There's no reason to use `getElementById` directly in this case, it's not in a tight loop or anything, so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("#supplier, #formElementChargeRate, #formElementEmailIDS").change(validateForm);

});
```

Note that I've also removed the wrapper function from around `validateForm`. You may need to add it back if `validateForm` has a return value, and you don't want that return value to be used by jQuery (specifically: if it returned `false`, jQuery would stop propagation and prevent the default action of the `change` event).

If you really wanted to have direct access to the DOM elements using those variables:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var drpSupplier, drpChargeRate, drpIDSEmail;
    var formLevel2DDs       = [
        drpSupplier         = document.getElementById('supplier'),
        drpChargeRate       = document.getElementById('formElementChargeRate'),
        drpIDSEmail         = document.getElementById('formElementEmailIDS')
    ];

    $(formLevel2DDs).change(validateForm);
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, why the third option is not recommended? because jQuery object is heavy?

Comment: Just curious, why is #3 not recommended.

Comment: Of course (looking again), they ***are*** DOM elements in the OP's code! Reordered the options and removed the non-recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use `.each()` you must wrap the array with jQuery like this

```
$(formLevel2DDs).each(function() {
```

It's not necessary to use a loop in this case, just use `.change()` on the array wrapped with jQuery

```
$(formLevel2DDs).change(function(){
       validateForm()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The native iterator function is `forEach`, not `each`.

The jQuery `.each` function takes just one argument, that being the callback. The callback function is passed two parameters: the index into the list, and the value. The callback is invoked such that the list value is also the `this` value.

With `forEach`, the parameters are passed in reverse order: the value is first, followed by the index. The native function also passes the entire array as the third parameter. The native function does not bind `this` when the callback is invoked unless a second parameter is passed to `.forEach` *after* the callback function. If there is such a parameter, it is used as the value of `this` in the callback.

The native iterator skips elements of the array that have not been set.  The jQuery `.each()` does not skip such elements, instead always iterating from index 0 to `length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(formLevel2DDs).each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        validateForm()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

added one line

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var drpSupplier         = document.getElementById('supplier');
    var drpChargeRate       = document.getElementById('formElementChargeRate');
    var drpIDSEmail         = document.getElementById('formElementEmailIDS');
    var formLevel2DDs       = new Array();

    formLevel2DDs.push(drpSupplier);
    formLevel2DDs.push(drpChargeRate);
    formLevel2DDs.push(drpIDSEmail);

    formLevel2DDs = jQuery(formLevel2DDs);//this line
    formLevel2DDs.each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            validateForm()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: formLevel2DDs = jQuery(formLevel2DDs);

Answer (score -3):

use a for ... in loop

```
for(key in formLevel2DDs) { ... }
```

Comment: One shouldn't generally use `for ... in` to iterate through the numbered properties of an array.

Comment: jQuery.each() uses a for ... in loop.

Comment: jQuery only uses `for ... in` when the object being iterated is **not** an array.  There are many reasons not to use `for ... in` for arrays, and they're described in several questions on Stackoverflow.